# How to boot computer without acpi=off

Tags: boot, grub2

I recently bought an gaming laptop (**the Gigabyte Sabre 15**) with an Nvidia geforce gtx 1050. I had trouble with the graphic card during the installation of ubuntu and I had to boot with **acpi=off**.

Now everything is installed (including Nvidia drivers which was not as easy as usual) and i don't want my computer to boot with **acpi=off** anymore because it causes trouble with my keyboard and touchpad. I can disable it at start up by going into the grub and then by erasing "acpi=off" in the boot parameter, but then it works just once. And i don't want to do it at every boot.

Someone could give me a permanent solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To permanently remove `acpi=off`from the GRUB options, you have to edit the file `/etc/default/grub`.

You'll find a line like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

or similar (the important part is `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and obviously there should be `acpi=off`).

Just remove the `acpi=off` part (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`), save, exit and run

```
sudo update-grub
```