# Can't install Ubuntu 21.10 on my laptop

Tags: live-usb, boot-repair

So a few months ago I decided to install Ubuntu 21.10 on my ASUS X541U laptop from a live USB device, everything went fine and could use it for a few days, but I couldn't set up wifi so I resinstalled Ubuntu. And then I couldn't get to the installation screen, I could only get to the update screen and then everything froze. I tried everything I could do but nothing worked.

I did managed to use the "Try Ubuntu" button in graphic mode and worked, but didn't worked when I tried to install it, same problem as before.

Now I'm stuck with this error, it appears each time I use "Try Ubuntu".

[image]

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live USB, open `terminal`, type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`, then go to manufacturer's web site and check for a newer BIOS. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I've tried that, but I can't find the newer BIOS version and it seems I have the most recent version.

Comment: Show me the output of the dmidecode command, and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your  computer. You've written ASUS X541U, but there must be more to it... like X541UA or X541UAK, etc.

Comment: @heynnema The model is ASUS X451U, the model number is G9N0CV133268383. The output for the dmidecode command is `X541UA.307`

Comment: Your BIOS is current. I don't have any further suggestions for you.

Answer (score 2):

These can be resolved by making some changes in your UEFI/BIOS, but not all notebooks allow people to change the settings. That said, let's look at the two issues:

```
[Firmware Bug]: No firmware reserved region can cover this RMRR
```

To resolve this, you will need to disable VT-d.

```
[Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover the response buffer.
```

To resolve this, you will need to disable TPM. Note that a lot of notebooks will not allow people to do this.

---

If you can only disable VT-d, then the machine will boot properly after showing the `ACPI region` message. If the machine continues to freeze during the installation process, you may need to disable `acpi` at boot. Here is how:

0. Reboot the machine
1. At the Grub menu, make sure the "Try Ubuntu" menu item is highlighted, then press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
2. Go to the line that contains `quiet splash` and add `acpi=off` to the end. Everything should look like this:
   [image: Grub Config]
3. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with those settings.

Now you should be able to install Ubuntu without the system stalling on you. Do note that after installing Ubuntu, you will need to once again update your boot configuration to have `acpi=off`. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1110854/1222991) will walk you through that process.

Comment: So I did tried to disable VT-d, and I could use the "Try Ubuntu" button, but I'm still stick at the update and software screen when I'm trying to install.

Comment: @Niflax I've updated the answer to include some additional steps that should work for your machine.

Comment: Almost worked. The installation went great with no problem, until the end it said "Execution of «grub-install/dev/sda has failed». This error is fatal" and then the installation stoped.

Comment: Have you disabled Legacy Boot mode in your UEFI/BIOS?

Comment: Nope , I haven't, I'll try that

Comment: So I tried to find the legacy boot mode in my UEFI/BIOS, and I don't really find it, I did found something similar in the USB configuration of the BIOS/UEFI named Legacy USB Support, I don't know of this could help in any way.